# How to solve this thermal equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, mathematics

I was studying and came across a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. In fact, I think it gives me 1 degree of freedom. In the problem, I am asked to calculate the time and temperature required to reach thermal steady state.
A perfectly stirred tank reactor with a coil is turned on and allowed to reach a steady state from a thermal perspective before the reactants are fed into the tank. It is worth mentioning that thermal equilibrium is achieved by incorporating a water stream at a rate of 1.2 kg/s with T = 50°C and removing water from the tank at a rate of 0.9 kg/s. The tank dimensions are D = 1 m and height h = 2 m. The effective heat transfer area to the surroundings is 95%. Additionally, the initial mass is 100 kg and the temperature is T = 15°C. Finally, a coolant fluid circulates through the coil at a constant temperature of -3°C, and there is heat loss to the environment given by the expression h·Aestanque·(Ts-Tambiente). Assume that Ts is 3.5°C lower than the temperature of the fluid inside the reactor at any time, and h = 10 W m-2K-1.

With this data, what came to mind is assuming that the coil is the same length as the reactor and has a diameter of 1.7m. It is a copper tube of 1/4 inch that circulates water. With this information, I thought of using the design equation. With that data and the specific heat capacity of water, I should be able to calculate the watts of the system and step-by-step for each second (obviously, Python will do it). I would like to know if this is the appropriate way to solve it or if there is another method to approach it.